# How to Axle replacement

Tags: axle, size, skewer

2021 gt pro series 26 inch.  We cut the lugs off to get the wheel off. Would anyone know what size replacement or even where to get it?

Comment: You cut the lugs off the wheel's axle?  On a bike that isn't even 6 months old?  What stopped you from simply unbolting the wheel nuts ?

Comment: What do you mean with 'lugs'? The foot-pegs?

Comment: If this is your method of wheel removal going forward you may want several spares.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.gtbicycles.com/can_en/pro-series-26  the bmx comes with:

> Rear Hub :    Alloy Thread-on Disc Body, Sealed Bearings, Cr-Mo 3/8" Slotted 14mm Axle, 36h, 17mm Nut.

So you need a complete replacement 14mm axle, and probably new nuts as well.

Comment: Thank you. My son stripped everything on the axle he used his fathers battery operated tighteners‍♀️  but we found a shop to replace the full axle. I was suprised Pacific cycle couldnt help with a full oem wheel or any part. Appreciate your help